# не работает ничего в коде

Tags: python

```py
n=int(input('введи число -> '))
c=10
for i in range(1,n//1):
    w=c/i
print(w)
```

#Дано натуральное число NN. Вычисли:1 / 2 / 3 / . / N1/2/3/./N.

Comment: Предоставьте ваш вопрос в виде кода.

Comment: А что должно работать если ничего нет?

Comment: Я человек простой, вижу ругань в коде - сразу минусую.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам нужен такой исправленный код, чтобы вычислить `1/2/3/.../N`:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0/BViEzr0QjM6@gtERD/cImINx6YcuFHRebLmxVuNgOZDRe2H1hn4KunYK6piZXOVC9IVdafpFCJlCfQlFiXnqqhpGOQp6CtoKhphWXAhCUK@gDDeUqKAIZXK75/78xAA)

```py
n = int(input('введите число -> '))
w = 1
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    w /= i
print(w)
```

Ввод: `3`

Вывод: `0.1666666666`